Output file field description in paragraph.html.twig
How do I output the description for the file field in Drupal 10? I was hoping {{ content.field_files['#description'] }} or {{ content.field_files.0['#description'] }} may do it but nope.
I attach the dump screen and description field
Thanks



Stumbled across the answer if it helps others {{ content.field_files['#items'].description }}
